# Sending a pdf attachment from site on button click without mailto spam

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have a site where I'd like users to send a document (preferably) a pdf file or word doc on button click to a specific email address.
I read that mailto is not a good way to do it because of all the potential spam thats possible from spambots. Disassembling and reassembling the email address doesn't seem that hard to crack either. I don't understand how encoding works so I'd be grateful if someone explains that.
What I would like is: when the user clicks the send button, it opens up an email client with the address of the recipient and of course the mail client would have the ability to send attachments. Whats a good way spam protected way to do this?

Comment: That should be done on the server side, isn't hat an option?

Comment: Thing is, I don't want it to be handled from the server side. I'd like the person to use his own email client with a pre-populated recipient address and since the email client will behave like a regular contact form I don't have to provide any added security. Is this a good idea? would it work across all devices and browsers? If not, I guess I will have to look at how to handle it on the server side.

Comment: You should re-think the whole thing. It won't work what you are planning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mailto protocol does not include attachments. And it would be a huge security issue as well. Some Outlook-related examples can be found on the internet, but in the case it has been working in the past, it is not possible nowadays and at least not platform independent in every case.

Comment: But i should be able to add an attachment once im in my own email client right? But thanks for the clarification. Il encode the address before using mailto.

Comment: Of course, because then it's in the hand of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send files with mailto. What you should do instead, which would also protect you from spam bots, is upload the file to your server and send the mail with the attached file from there.